# ruby sass cannot compile bootstrap

Tags: ruby, sass, rubygems, bootstrap-sass

I'm using ruby 3.1.2p20, gem 3.3.7, sass: ruby sass 3.7.4 and having a problem. I can't compile the bootstrap, my bootstrap version is "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.5", "react-bootstrap": "^0.23.3", "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.18.1". I found the error from the node_modules\bootstrap-sass\assets\stylesheets\bootstrap\_variables.scss

The error like this

> Error: Invalid CSS after "...     floor(math": expected ")", was ".div($grid-gutt..."
> on line 369 of node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss
> from line 8 of node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss
> from line 2 of src/styles/global/libraries.scss
> from line 4 of ./src/styles/app.scss

code from "_variables.scss" that having error:

```
$navbar-padding-horizontal: floor(math.div($grid-gutter-width, 2)) !default;
$navbar-padding-vertical: math.div(($navbar-height - $line-height-computed), 2) !default;
```

Comment: any success with that?